# Creating a C string parser

Tags: c

In C (and similar languages), a string is declared for example as `"abc"`. Another example is `"ab\"c"`. I have a file which contains these strings. That is, the file contents is `"abc"` or `"ab\c"` etc. Any literal string that can be defined in a .c file can be defined in the file I'm reading.

These strings can be malformed. E.g. `"abc` (no closing quotes). What is the best way to write a parser to make sure the string in the file is a valid C literal string? (so that if I copy the file contents and paste them after `char* str =`, the resulting expression will be accepted by the compiler when at the top of a function)

The strings are each in a separate line.

Alternatively, you can think of this as wanting to parse lines that declare literal string variables. Imagine I'm grepping a big file and use `char\* .* = (.*);$` and want to make sure the part in the parenthesis will not cause compilation errors;

Comment: Is each string on a new line?

Comment: @Carcigenicate the string ends at the end of the line.

Comment: @SourabhChoure yes

Comment: Then I guess you already have the answer with you.

Comment: Are you writing a string parser in C, or are you writing a "C string" parser in some other language?

Comment: And after parsing the file do you want to lose those trouble-making characters? like `"abc` to become `abc` or do you want to retent them by converting it to `\"abc\"` or just adding the escape character`\"abc`

Comment: @user3386109 writing a "C string" parser in C.

Comment: @SourabhChoure I want to lose them

Comment: if the string literal is in the C file you do not have to write this parser. The parser is called the `compiler`

Comment: The best way is probably a state machine. This will get rather large (maybe 20..30 states?) if you want to recognise `\n`, `\0377` and '\x0d` inside the strings, too.

Comment: https://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/176675-how-remove-all-occurrences-word-file-c-post1281073.html#post1281073 You can check this out, they managed to read contents from one file and then wrote the content to another file without the specified character.

Comment: See `flex`, what should be sufficient is *tokenizing* the input and checking that it contains only string tokens

Comment: `What is the best way to write a parser to make sure the string in the file is a valid C literal string?` is opinion based question. The best way is just to write any parser to do it at all.

Answer (score 3):

The grammar for C string literals is given in C 2018 6.4.5. Supposing you want to parse only plain strings, not those with encoding prefixes such as `u` in `u"xyz"`, then the grammar for a *string-literal* is `"` *s-char-sequence*<sub>opt</sub> `"`, where “opt” means optional and *s-char-sequence* is one or more *s-char* tokens. An *s-char* is any member of the source character set except `"`, `\` or the new-line character or is an *escape-sequence*.

The source character set includes at least the Latin alphabet (26 letters A-Z) in uppercase and lowercase, the ten digits, space, horizontal tab, vertical tab, form feed, and these characters:

```
"#%&’()*+,-./:;?[\]^_{|}~
```

However, a C implementation may include other characters in its source character set. Therefore, any character found in the string other than `"`, `\`, or the new-line character must be accepted as potentially valid in some C implementation.

An *escape-sequence* is defined in 6.4.4.4 1 to be one of:

- `\` followed by `'`, `"`, `?`, `\`, `a`, `b`, `f`, `n`, `r`, `t`, `v`,
- `\` followed by one to three octal digits, or
- `\x` followed by one or more hexadecimal digits, or
- a *universal-character-name*.

Paragraph 7 says:

> Each octal or hexadecimal escape sequence is the longest sequence of characters that can constitute the escape sequence.

A *universal-character-name* is defined in 6.4.3 to be `\u` followed by four hexadecimal digits or `\U` followed by eight hexadecimal digits. Paragraph 2 limits these:

> A universal character name shall not specify a character whose short identifier is less than 00A0 other than 0024 ($), 0040 (@), or 0060 (‘), nor one in the range D800 through DFFF inclusive.

This part of the C grammar looks fairly simple to parse:

- A string literal must start with a `"`.
- If the next character is anything other than `"`, `\`, or a new-line character, then accept it.
- If the next character is `\` and it is followed by one of the single characters listed above, accept it and the following character.
- If the next character is `\` and it is followed by one to three octal digits, accept it and up to three octal digits.
- If the next two characters are `\x` and are followed by a hexadecimal digit, accept them and all the hexadecimal digits that follow.
- If the next two characters are `\u` and are followed by four hexadecimal digits, accept those six characters. However, if the value is one of those prohibited in the constraint above, this is not a valid C string literal.
- If the next two characters are `\U` and are followed by eight hexadecimal digits, accept those ten characters. However, if the value is one of those prohibited in the constraint above, this is not a valid C string literal.
- Repeat the above until the next character is not accepted.
- If the next character is not `"`, this is not a valid C string literal.
- If the next character is `"`, accept it.
- If that is the end of the line read from the file, it is a valid C string literal. Otherwise, it is not.

Comment: There's also concatenation of adjacent string literals, and predefined string literals like `__FILE__`. Both satisfy OP's rather loose requirement *"that if I copy [...] paste them after `char* str =`, the resulting expression will be accepted by the compiler"* For example, the line `"hello, " /* comment */ __FILE__` is valid by OP's definition.

Comment: @user3386109: Considering arbitrary function calls and other expressions could be placed there, as well as `;` followed by arbitrary statements and declarations, I do not think that is what they really want. They did not cite that as a clear definition of what they want, just an example for illustration.